# How to show listiview in app widget android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget, widget

> I am trying to make an app widget for lockscreen which shows listview.
>   But i am getting problem showing listview in appwidget.

Comment: @Apoorva Faldu This doesnot help.Actually code which you provided only helps to update the widget.Actually i want to update all the list of app widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@saugat man ligal - You can find the Listview demo from the give link above :

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

And you can make use of the Button to sync or refresh your listview like this :

```
package com.automatic.widget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String SYNC_CLICKED    = "automaticWidgetSyncButtonClick";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    ComponentName watchWidget;

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sync_button, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.sync_button, "TESTING");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

    }
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
}
```

So now you can integrate it and make Refresh ListView Working... Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

CommonsGuy has a sample in GitHub using a ListView in a homescreen widget :

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

Comment: oh thanks .I also want to create a button in xml layout for widget and want to refresh whole listview of the app widget.How can i do it?